# How to change mysql timezone running on inuxmint in virtual box?

Tags: mysql, timezone, mariadb

I want to change timezone in mysql from EDT to GMT ,

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone;
+--------------------+
| @@system_time_zone |
+--------------------+
| EDT                |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

on researching google I am hitting its not possible ! I am pretty sure it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the current session, just:

```
SET @@session.time_zone='+00:00'; -- UTC
```

Or:

```
SET time_zone = '+00:00';
```

To make it permanent, you can change mysqld conf file (requires a server restart):

```
default_time_zone='+00:00'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ec22c7c71f3c84faa60920a1bc997479)**:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

```
@@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone
:----------------- | :------------------
SYSTEM             | SYSTEM
```

```
SET @@session.time_zone='+00:00';

SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

```
@@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone
:----------------- | :------------------
SYSTEM             | +00:00
```

Comment: well no, I ran didn't made any difference

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz: how about `SET time_zone = '+00:00'`?

Comment: Also: what do you see when you run `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` after making the changes?

Comment: this is how I got it fixed `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`; thanks you were right though, I spotted the word `SYSTEM` which meant linux not mysql .